# Django - create or delete object

Tags: django

I am wondering what is the best way of creating (if it doesn't exist) or deleting (if it does exist) an object in Django.

I know I can do something like this:

```
if Like.objects.filter(user=request.user, post=post).exists():
    Like.objects.filter(user=request.user, post=post).delete()
else:
    Like.objects.create(user=request.user, post=post)
```

Is there a better way, like for instance the `get_or_create` method that Django provides?

Comment: funny requirement

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it's a single object do this:

```
try:
    Like.objects.get(user=request.user, post=post).delete()
except Like.DoesNotExist
    Like.objects.create(...)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for something like this. Looks more concise and readable than what I had.

Comment: @Dalvtor note that delete a heavy action for db, so you may need to consider using update instead of delete/create

Answer (score 0):

```
Like.objects.filter(user=request.user, post=post).delete()
Like.objects.create(...)
```